# Find the value of $\lambda$ that maximises the area of a triangle on a hyperbola.

Tags: conic-sections

> > Consider the hyperbola: $$ \frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{y^2}{36}=1$$
> >
> > $l_1$ and $l_2$ are the asymptotes
> >
> > [image]
> >
> > Consider a case where $P$ is located in the first quadrant. Through $P$, draw another line $CD$, where $C$  is on line $l_1$, D is on line $l_2$, and $P$ is between $C$ and $D$, such that $CP:PD=1: \lambda $
> >
> > Find the value of $\lambda$, which will minimise the area of the triangle $COD$, and find this area.

What I have done:

The asymptotes of the graph are $y=3x$ and $y=-3x$

The point $P$ lies on the hyperbola so let the coordinates of this point be $(x_0 , y_0)$ with the properties that $x_0 >0$ and hence $ \frac{x_0^2}{4}-\frac{y_0^2}{36}=1$ which implies that $x_0 = \frac{\sqrt{36+y_0^2}}{3}$

The point $D$ is determined by $C$ and $P$ , so let's find C, a point $(c_1,c_2)$ with the properties that $c_1>0$ and $c_2=3c_1$

This is where I am stuck , I don't know if my approach is correct and even if it is I feel like the algebra is too complex , there should be a more simpler way of doing this.

Comment: What you wrote is not a hyperbola but just a mathematical expression. Did you mean $$\frac{x^2}4-\frac{y^2}{36}\color{red}{=1}\;?$$

Comment: Ah yes sorry my bad

Comment: "maximises" in the title should be changed.

Answer (score 4):

Rishi has already provided a good answer.

This answer shows the detail on how to find the coordinates of $P$ and a way to find the minimum area of $\triangle{COD}$ without using derivatives.

Let $C(x_1,3x_1),D(x_2,-3x_2)$.

Since $CP:PD=1:\lambda$ leads that $\vec{CP}=\frac{1}{\lambda+1}\vec{CD}$, we get $$\vec p=\vec c+\frac{1}{\lambda+1}(\vec d-\vec c)=\frac{\lambda \vec c+\vec d}{\lambda+1}$$to have
$P(\frac{\lambda x_1+x_2}{\lambda+1},\frac{3x_1\lambda-3x_2}{\lambda+1})$.

Since $P$ is on the hyperbola, we get
$$\frac 14\left(\frac{\lambda x_1+x_2}{\lambda+1}\right)^2-\frac{1}{36}\left(\frac{3x_1\lambda-3x_2}{\lambda+1}\right)^2=1,$$
i.e.
$$x_1x_2=\frac{(\lambda+1)^2}{\lambda}\tag1$$

Also, letting $\alpha=\angle{COD}$, we get that 
$$[\triangle{COD}]=\frac 12\times\overline{OC}\times\overline{OD}\times\sin{\alpha}=\frac 12\sqrt{x_1^2+9x_1^2}\sqrt{x_2^2+9x_2^2}\times\frac 35=3x_1x_2\tag2$$
where $\sin{\alpha}=2\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}=2\times\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}=\frac 35$ since $\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}=3$.

From $(1)(2)$, we get, by the AM-GM inequality,
$$[\triangle{COD}]=3\times\frac{(\lambda+1)^2}{\lambda}=3\left(\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda}+2\right)\ge 3\left(2+2\right)=12$$
Therefore, the minimum area of $\triangle{COD}$ is $\color{red}{12}$ when $\lambda=\frac{1}{\lambda}$, i.e. $\color{red}{\lambda=1}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I was wondering if there was anyway I could continue with my method?

Comment: I also don't understand: Since $CP:PD=1:\lambda$ leads that $\vec{CP}=\frac{1}{\lambda+1}\vec{CD}$

Comment: @dydxx: To the first comment : Yes, you can, but anyway you will need to use the formula for internal division of a line segment. If you don't want to use the formula, then I think you have to have very tedious calculations. To the second : $P$ is on the line segment $CD$ with $CP:PD=1:\lambda$. So, there is a positive real number $k$ such that $|CP|=k,|PD|=k\lambda,|CD|=|CP|+|PD|=k(\lambda+1)$. So, $|CP|=\frac{1}{\lambda+1}|CD|$ holds and so $\vec{CP}=\frac{1}{\lambda+1}\vec{CD}$ holds. Drawing the line segment $CD$ should help.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, to the first comment of what you said , I do not want to use the internal division formula and I want to continue on with my method. If you could show me how in another comment I will gladly give you the +50. :)

Comment: @dydxx: Well, you already have $C(c_1,3c_1),P(\sqrt{36+y_0^2}/3,y_0)$. You can determine $D$ by $C,P$ since $D$ is the intersection point of $y=-3x$ with the line $CP$. Now, representing $CP^2$ and $PD^2$ by $y_0,c_1$ and using $CP:PD=1:\lambda$, i.e. $\lambda^2\times CP^2=PD^2$ will give you a relation between $y_0,c_1,\lambda$. Then, you will be able to represent the area of $\triangle{COD}$ by $\lambda$, and done.

Comment: @dydxx: My suggestion might not work. In other words, your method without using internal division formula might not work. Let $D(d,-3d)$. Then, we can determine $d$ by $y_0,c_1$ and get $[\triangle{COD}]=3cd$. However, I found it very difficult (maybe impossible) to represent $3cd$ by $\lambda$ using $\lambda^2\times CP^2=PD^2$ instead of $CP:PD=1:\lambda$. So, if we don't use $CP:PD=1:\lambda$ itself (i.e. the formula itself), we might not be able to find the answer. This is all I can say now. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi I will accept your answer , however do you know of any other method of solving this question?

Comment: @dydxx: Thanks. Well, sorry but I have no idea. From the condition $CP:PD=1:\lambda$, the internal division formula gives us **two** pieces of information, i.e. the information for $x$ and information for $y$. However, if we don't use the formula, I think that we have to use the condition in the form $\lambda^2\times CP^2=PD^2$, i.e. the relation of the lengths of some line segments. This form of the condition gives us only one piece of information, i.e. we can't separate it into $x$ and $y$. So, I think that the key is to use the internal division formula.

Comment: It's just that this question was given and I had no clue what the internal division formula was so I was extremely confused how to start solving this question! So I posted it here that maybe there would be an answer without using it. Anyways thank you for your comprehensive answer as always. Take care.

Comment: @dydxx: I see, and you are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You can let $C$ have coordinates $(x_1,y_1)$ and $D$ have coordinates $(x_2,y_2)$.

Hence P has coordinates $(\frac{\lambda x_1+x_2}{\lambda +1},\frac{\lambda y_1+y_2}{\lambda +1})$

Asymptotes have equations $y=3x$ and $y=-3x$, hence $y_1=3x_1$ and $y_2=-3x_2$

Therefore P has coordinates $(\frac{\lambda x_1+x_2}{\lambda +1},\frac{3\lambda x_1-3x_2}{\lambda +1})$.

P also lies on the hyperbola hence substituting these coordinates into the equation of the hyperbola will get you a relationship between $x_1x_2$ and $\lambda$.
This allows you to find an expression for the area in terms of $\lambda$  which can then be minimised with derivatives.

Comment: How did you get the P coordinates? Still confused about that.

Comment: It's the formula for internal division of a line segment